# Ajax data variable is confusing for me, what I should put if I use only Javascript? (No JSON or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Well, yesterday I started learning how to use AJAX and well I saw this page: http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/ where everything was well explained. So, I coded the next:

```
if(isset($_POST['edited'])) {
    $real_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['real_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
    $date_day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_day']);
    $date_month = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_month']);
    $date_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_year']);
    $final_date = $date_day."-".$date_month."-".$date_year;
    $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']);
    $web_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['web_title']);
    $web_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['web_url']);
    $skype = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['skype']);
    if($my_stats['real_name'] != $_POST['real_name']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET real_name = '$real_name' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['email'] != $_POST['email']) {
        $act = md5(time());
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET email = '$email' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET activation = '$act' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
        mail($email, 'GimmeAHit! - Activación de correo', '¡Hola! Para activar tu cuenta visita el siguiente link: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/?action=act&code='.$act);
    }
    if($my_stats['gender'] != $_POST['gender']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET gender = '$gender' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['birthdate'] != $final_date) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET birthdate = '$final_date' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['location'] != $_POST['location']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET location = '$location' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['web_title'] != $_POST['web_title']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET web_title = '$web_title' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['web_url'] != $_POST['web_url']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET web_url = '$web_url' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
    if($my_stats['skype'] != $_POST['skype']) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET skype = '$skype' WHERE id = '$my_id'");
    }
}
```

And my AJAX call:

```
echo '<script>
    function showUpdateNode(elem) {
        elem.parentNode.childNodes[1].style.display = "none";
        elem.parentNode.childNodes[2].style.display = "inline";
        elem.parentNode.childNodes[3].style.display = "none";
    }
    function sendSForm() {
        var real_name = document.getElementById("real_name").value;
        var date_day = document.getElementById("day_select").value;
        var date_month = document.getElementById("month_select").value;
        var date_year = document.getElementById("year_select").value;
        var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
        var web_title = document.getElementById("website_title").value;
        var web_url = document.getElementById("website_url").value;
        var skype = document.getElementById("skype").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var dataString = "real_name="+real_name+"&date_day="+date_day+"&date_month="+date_month+"&date_year="+date_year+"&gender="+gender+"&location="+location+"&web_title="+web_title+"&web_url="+web_url+"&skype="+skype+"&email="+email+"&edited=a";
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/sources/edit_profile.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>';
```

Everything is in the same file, but for some reason when I make the AJAX call, nothing happens...

I tried to know what exactly happens, with `success: function(html) {alert(html);}` and `if(isset($_POST['edited']) {echo "Okay!";}` but the alert is empty!..

Maybe something is wrong with the `dataString` variable, what can you see where I went wrong? Any suggetion?

**Edit** There aren't errors in the console :/ (I think that the error is in PHP, but where, I think all is right...)

Comment: Open the browser's console window (F12) and look for errors.

Comment: The console is empty... :/

Comment: How about requests and responses when you perform the AJAX?

Comment: How can I check this? (I'm a newbie, I started coding AJAX yesterday as I said) If you mean inside PHP, I tried echoing the result and showing them with alerts but nothing happens...

Comment: Are you sure `sendSForm()` is being called? What's the value of `dataString` right before the `$.ajax()` call? BTW, `$.ajax()` *is* a jQuery method, so you might want to rethink your title.

Comment: There are several tabs in your developer tools window depending on the browser. [Chrome has a great "how-to" guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

Comment: Your `success: function(html) {alert(html);}` will be empty, because you do not `echo` anything in your ajax. Also, is your table is updated?

Comment: Yes, sendSForm is called, and if I use console.log, I see the next: `real_name=&date_day=17&date_month=7&date_year=1998&gender=1&location=&web_title=&web_url=&skype=&email=&edited=a`

Comment: @lolka_bolka I only use alerts if I echo something, but as you can see I don't use alerts in the mainly code..

Comment: I do not really know, what do you expect? What should happens? What is the desired result? And as i asked, is your table updated?

Comment: *Sorry for the late msg I was busy...* What do you mean by `tables updated` (no joke, I didn't completely understood you), and the desired result is to update the mysql information in my tables. (If you mean this, no this isn't updated.. :/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but just a refactoring suggestion: Use arrays!  Make an array of gender, birthday, etc..., and loop through that array.  In the loop, compare `$my_stat[$field]` with `$_POST[$field]` and the query can be `"UPDATE users SET $field = '".$_POST['gender']."' WHERE id = '$my_id'"`

Comment: Under the network tab in your development console, do you see new requests being issued when you submit the form? To check for errors in php, enable error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', true);` Furthermore, I see no calls to `sendSForm();`

Comment: Thanks, @JustinE, I fixed it using your solution... I forgot to look the error_log... The problem was that mysql isn't included when you call a PHP file from AJAX... :P